# Keyboard layout aware combinations in pygame

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame, keyboard-layout

Pygame has a constant for example for the exclamation mark, !. The constant is called `pygame.K_EXCLAIM`. However, in my standard US keyboard layout, the exclamation mark is produced by pressing shift and the key 1. Consider the following two snippets:

```
# snippet 1
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_EXCLAIM:
            print('!')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_1:
            print('1')

# snippet 2
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed[pygame.K_EXCLAIM]:
    print('!')
if pressed[pygame.K_1]:
    print('1')
```

In both cases, when I press Shift+1, which would produce a exclamation mark, pygame does not recognize the combination and simply says the shift key and the 1 key are pressed, printing the value "1". This concerns me a little bit because while I can hardcode such combinations, they are dependent of the keyboard's layout.

Can I make pygame produce combinations constants (such as `K_EXCLAIM` or `K_AMPERSAND`) in a keyboard layout-aware manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `event.unicode` attribute:

```
if event.unicode == "!":
     print("!")
```

Comment: Interesting, but it does not seem to work with Shift+NumPad3 to produce a PageDown. Could that also be achieved?

Comment: @Mephy Untestet!! Could you please test and report?

Comment: That hardcodes the keyboard layout though, I'm trying to avoid that ;) I guess unicode will be good enough.